# I'm looking for a Rails 3 forum application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Does anybody know about a Rails 3 forum application?

Before anyone says anything...I've posted this previously but I got the post closed due to a "possible duplicate"...but it's not! The post "I duplicated" mentions **Rails 2** forums. And I've asked for **Rails 3** forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altered Beast :

https://github.com/stiff/altered_beast

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a gem, here you are a nice gem compatible with Rails 3 https://github.com/radar/forem

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/gitt/forum_monster

This forum monster is quite updated.  If I'm not wrong, it's forked from the abandoned beast.

Answer (score 4):

You can check this link for reference : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/building-a-forum-from-scratch-with-ruby-on-rails/

This is not in Rails 3, but I have created an application following the same in Rails 3 without facing any issue. I agree that many things have been deprecated in Rails 3, but still you can create an app in it which was already implemented in older version.

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide further requirements? Are you looking to develop the forums yourself? Do you want to install as a gem?

If you're looking for example source, this may fit the bill: https://github.com/smholloway/Rails3-forum or https://github.com/smholloway/Rails3-Forums-Without-Nesting

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to an up to date list of popular Ruby forum systems: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/forum_systems

Currently, [Forem](https://github.com/radar/forem) seems to be the system of choice.